# Code not executed slows down program

Tags: c

I have a line of code which is in an if statement that is never met currently the way I have it configured. It slows down my program massively. It is just a print statement, however if  I just declare a variable in this statement it runs perfectly. I don't understand as this line of code is never executed so why would it slow down my program.

Sorry for the lack of code but the program is very large, and the line of code in question is just one if statement.

Could this be a branch prediction issue. It has to be something to do with the compiler surely?

Comment: `I have a line of code`..care to show us?

Comment: and maybe a few of the lines surrounding it too :)

Comment: Up to now it's a very bad question... hope you could edit it later (e.g. post codes).

Comment: could ce a processor cache issue, or perhaps the does is doing more than you think.

Comment: The code that does not execute **never** slows down the program. In fact it is the fastest code one could ever write.

Comment: Code that never execute don't mean code that it's not there, it could slow down the program indirectly (ex: miss branch prediction, miss i-cache, etc...).

Comment: Show both versions of the code the slowed down one and the fast one. Then maybe you will get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Well, show that small part of the code 5 lines before and 5 lines after. Without this all answers and comments are guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a conditional statement controlling the flow of the execution of this line ... (the line wrapped in a if) ... then there is potentially some branch prediction going on in the CPU running your program. 
Even without branch-prediction issues, the condition has to be tested each time.

If this is about debug prints, change to using pre-processor logic so the statement and surrounding if-branch is never compiled into the resulting executable when you are not debugging.
Something in the lines of:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
your_statement_here
#endif
```

The downside is that you cannot toggle debugging on and off during runtime, but you wanted performance, right? :)